# Number guessing game finishes before it even starts

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am working with xamarim.ios and have a problem in the code below:

```
using System;

using UIKit;

namespace SingleViewApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        int count = 0;
        int countFrom = 8;
        int guess;
        bool run = false;

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        textView.Text = $"Can you guess my number in {countFrom} or less tries? Number: ";

    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    partial void EnterButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.Next(1, 1001);

        try
        {
            while (!run)
            {
                guess = Convert.ToInt32(guessInput.Text);

                if (guess == number && count <= 8)
                {
                    textView.Text = $"Congrats, you won! Guessed in {count + 1} guesses.";

                    run = true;
                }
                else if (guess != number && count >= 8)
                {
                    textView.Text = $"You lose! The number was {number}.";

                    run = true;
                }
                else if (guess == (number - 25))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

                }
                else if (guess == (number + 25))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

                }
                else if (guess <= (number - 50))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

                }
                else if (guess == (number + 50))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

                }
                else if (guess == (number - 75))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

                }
                else if (guess == (number + 75))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

                }
                else if (guess == (number - 100))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

                }
                else if (guess == (number + 100))
                {
                    textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 2) && guess <= (number + 2))
                {
                    textView.Text = "You're practically there (2) !";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 5) && guess <= (number + 5))
                {
                    textView.Text = "You're very close (5) !";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 13) && guess <= (number + 13))
                {
                    textView.Text = "You are close (13) !";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 25) && guess <= (number + 25))
                {
                    textView.Text = "It's warmer.";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 50) && guess <= (number + 50))
                {
                    textView.Text = "It's warm.";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 75) && guess <= (number + 75))
                {
                    textView.Text = "It's not too far anymore!";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number - 100) && guess <= (number + 100))
                {
                    textView.Text = "You are not quite there!";

                }
                else if (guess <= (number - 150))
                {
                    textView.Text = "You are too low!";

                }
                else if (guess >= (number + 150))
                {
                    textView.Text = "You are too high!";

                }
                else if (guess > number)
                {
                    textView.Text = "It's lower.";

                }
                else if (guess < number)
                {
                    textView.Text = "It's higher.";
                }

                count++;
                countFrom--;
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            textView.Text = "Wrong input!";

        }
    }
}
```

}

First of all the code is not good and makes unnecessary things or things that could be shortened or generally rewritten 
but my actual question is, why my app does 8 runs with the entered number and then outputs that ive lost before the game even started?
when the first run finishes i should be able to enter the next number/try

Comment: trace your code..  You can watch what happens to those variables and it should answer your own question

Comment: Ive added breakpoints and i found out that it goes through the while loop 8 times with the initial guess remaining the same and then outputting that ive lost

Comment: the problem is that i cant enter a second or third guess and so on and i dont know why that is i made a console project with almost tje same code and it works fine

Comment: It looks like you only set the run flag to true when the game has finished and I don't see any code in the loop that asks for another number, just setting an output text value and reading a input text value.

Comment: Can you tell me what you would change in the code for this is my very first ios application and my c# is in the beginnet state

Comment: there're too many problems in your code, for example the value of `guess` cannot be changed if you don't hit the result, and `else if (guess != number && count >= 8)` is not a right condition as well.  what you need to do first is draw a flow about every situation, then prepare some test case and trace them.

Answer (score 1):

I have never created a iOS app so dont know what the best practice is but I would generate the number outside EnterButton and then I don't think you should need to loop at all.

```
using System;

using UIKit;

namespace SingleViewApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        int count = 0;
        int countFrom = 8;
        int guess;
        bool run = false;
        int number =0;

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        number = random.Next(1, 1001);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        textView.Text = $"Can you guess my number in {countFrom} or less tries? Number: ";

    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }



    partial void EnterButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        try
        {
            guess = Convert.ToInt32(guessInput.Text);

            if (guess == number && count <= 8)
            {
                textView.Text = $"Congrats, you won! Guessed in {count + 1} guesses.";

            }
            else if (guess != number && count >= 8)
            {
                textView.Text = $"You lose! The number was {number}.";
            }
            else if (guess == (number - 25))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

            }
            else if (guess == (number + 25))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

            }
            else if (guess <= (number - 50))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

            }
            else if (guess == (number + 50))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

            }
            else if (guess == (number - 75))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

            }
            else if (guess == (number + 75))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

            }
            else if (guess == (number - 100))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is higher than that!";

            }
            else if (guess == (number + 100))
            {
                textView.Text = "A hint: The number is lower than that!";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 2) && guess <= (number + 2))
            {
                textView.Text = "You're practically there (2) !";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 5) && guess <= (number + 5))
            {
                textView.Text = "You're very close (5) !";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 13) && guess <= (number + 13))
            {
                textView.Text = "You are close (13) !";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 25) && guess <= (number + 25))
            {
                textView.Text = "It's warmer.";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 50) && guess <= (number + 50))
            {
                textView.Text = "It's warm.";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 75) && guess <= (number + 75))
            {
                textView.Text = "It's not too far anymore!";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number - 100) && guess <= (number + 100))
            {
                textView.Text = "You are not quite there!";

            }
            else if (guess <= (number - 150))
            {
                textView.Text = "You are too low!";

            }
            else if (guess >= (number + 150))
            {
                textView.Text = "You are too high!";

            }
            else if (guess > number)
            {
                textView.Text = "It's lower.";

            }
            else if (guess < number)
            {
                textView.Text = "It's higher.";
            }

            count++;
            countFrom--;
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            textView.Text = "Wrong input!";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution i will try and report any progress

Comment: Your solution seems to work so far but i will do further testing. But thank you very much already